# Using Template Specific JavaScript in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a `base_generic.html` page in `django` that has the standard UI elements (navbar, footer, etc.), and I have a `list.html` page which extends the `base_generic.html` page. The `list.html` page is using a `javascript` function that is only used in this page, but for it to work, I have to include it in the `base_generic.html` page.

How can I include this `javascript` function in `list.html` using Django's built-in template tags and features?

Should I use `{% verbatim %}` or `{% scripts %}` or another tag template?

Should I include this inline with the `{% block content %}` that has the `html` for this `django` template, or should I place it before or after the `{% block content %}`?

Comment: "but for it to work, I have to include it in the base_generic.html page." Why, if you only need it in `list.html`?

Comment: `list.html` is a `django` template that `{% extends "base_generic.html" %}`.

Comment: Yes and it overrides anything inside the block content, so it does not need to be in "base_generic.html".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several ways of accomplish what you want:

- Just add the javascript snippet **inside** the `{% block content %}`

  {% block content %}

  my javascript();

  {% endblock content %}
- Use the `include` statement to a file with your javascript, again, **inside** the `{% block content %}`

  {% include 'my_javascript.html' %}

> In this way, you can reuse your javascript code on other pages.

- Create a new block in `base_generic.html`, like:

  {% block my_javascript %}{% endblock my_javascript %}

And in you child template, add the javascript as told in the first points iside these tags, in this case it can be outside or inside the `{% block content %}`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be working. I am adding my javascript at the bottom of `list.html` in `<script type="text/javascript>` `</script>` tags, before `{% endblock %}`, and it's not loading the `javascript` when I go to the page. When I paste the same code in `base_generic.html`, everything work fine. Any additional suggestions?

Comment: Never mind. Of course I had a typo when implementing your recommended solution. Everything works as it's supposed to. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be pass the path for the js file in your views.py:

```
context = {
        'scripts_to_include':['/static/js/my_js_file.js']
    }
```

You can obviously include multiple js files here. Then, in your template:

```
{% if scripts_to_include %}
   {% for script_url in scripts_to_include %}
      <script src="{{script_url}}"></script>
   {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

I like this, cause the js files can still be stored in a directory (instead of putting it right into html), JS files are also reusable.